# mongodb/mongoose arrayFilters (with $[]) update does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

My update using $[] refuses to work. Schema:

```
tables: {
    type: [
        {
            tableID: String,
            numberOfChairs: Number,
            reserved: Boolean,
            location: String,
            inDoors: Boolean,
            reservedDuring: [
                {
                    reservedFrom: Date,
                    reservedTo: Date,
                    reservedFor: {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'Consumer'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    required: false
},
```

My update function:

```
TableBooking.updateMany({}, {
    '$set': {
        'tables.$[].reservedDuring.$[arr].reservedFrom': Date.now()
    }
}, { arrayFilters: [{
        'arr.reservedFrom': { $gte: Date.now() }
    }],
    multi: true
}, ).then(function (doc)){}
```

My update function keeps returning "{"n":2,"nModified":0,"ok":1}". I have no idea why the function refuses to update the array element. I have 2 of docs where the arrayfliters' condition is met, but nothing is changed. I am using MongoDB 4.0 and mongoose 5.2.14 and @types/mongoose: 5.2.12 (I am writing my app in TS).

Comment: Cannot test right now, but think you missed 'type' field is your $set : 'tables.type.$[].reservedDuring...

Comment: @matthPen I have never seen the 'type' field used like that. Either way I tried, with every signle combination imaginable, and got "{"ok":0,"n":0,"nModified":0}" every single time. I belive mongodb was looking for fields named "type".

Comment: But you HAVE a field named type! According to your schema, tables is not an array, but tables.type is one. I'm not speaking about the type of the field

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you at first. But shouldnt my original implementation's result be "{"ok":0,"n":0,"nModified":0}"?? Either way I'm gonna experiment a bit. THanks.

Comment: provide sample data, i can tr on my side. Never tested both $[] and $[placeholder] together.

Comment: Okay, I tried by removint the "type" field and left there only the array, but got the same result: {"n":2,"nModified":0,"ok":1} :/

Comment: let tableBooking = new TableBooking();
 tableBooking.save().then(() => {
 let reservationArray = {
        tableID: theTables.tableID, numberOfChairs: theTables.numberOfChairs, reserved: theTables.reserved,
        location: theTables.location, inDoors: theTables.inDoors, reservedDuring: theTables.reservations
    };

    tblBooking.markModified('tables');
    TableBooking.findByIdAndUpdate(tblBooking._id, {
        '$push': {'tables': reservationArray}
    }, (err, model) => {
        
    });

Comment: That was the function that I use, but I recommend just creating a dummy in MongoDB Compass

Comment: :) When i said sample data, i was talking about json data from monodb, not the function you used to save your data !

Comment: pastebin dott comm / H0SX0MSX <- Here you can find the JSON

Comment: Okay @matthPen I was responded with the solution. The "types" part you originally mentioned was irrelevant, its not a different field, its just a type. 
SOLUTION: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I understand : you tell about date format in your schema, but in reality you store fields (reservedFrom and reservedTo) as String. So your arrayFilters is not matching the good results.
Moreover, Date.now() will return a timestamp, not a string representation of the date nor ISODate. 
My advice is to work with ISODate instead of String, because it's easier to manipulate. Here the code to achieve what you want :

```
db['TableBooking'].updateMany({}, {
    '$set': {
        'tables.$[].reservedDuring.$[arr].reservedFrom': new ISODate()
    }
}, { arrayFilters: [{
        'arr.reservedFrom': { $gte: new ISODate().toISOString() }
    }],
    multi: true
} )
```

If you still want to work with string instead of dates, you have to modify slightly this by adding .toISOString() at the new ISODATE() in the $set stage (exactly like in arrayFilters)